# Can we add static resource image in lightning treegrid?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, static-resources, hierarchy, lightningtreegrid

**COMPONENT:**

```
<lightning:treeGrid columns="{! v.gridColumns }"
    data="{! v.gridData }"
    keyField="name"
    expandedRows="{! v.gridExpandedRows}"
    aura:id="mytree" />
```

**CONTROLLER:**

```
({
    doInit: function (component, event, helper) { 
        console.log('doInit of component called');
        var columns = [
            {
                type: 'url',
                fieldName: 'AccountURL',
                label: 'Account Name',
                typeAttributes: {
                    label: { fieldName: 'accountName' }
                },
                cellAttributes: { iconName: 'utility:event', iconAlternativeText: 'Close Date' }
            },
            {
                type: 'text',
                fieldName: 'Industry',
                label: 'Industry',

                cellAttributes: { iconName: 'utility:event', iconAlternativeText: 'Close Date' }
            },
            {
                type: 'type',
                fieldName: 'Type',
                label: 'Type'
            }

        ];
        component.set('v.gridColumns', columns);


        var trecid = component.get('v.ltngcurrentRecId');
        //var tsObjectName= component.get('v.ltngSobjectname');
        //var tparentFieldAPIname= component.get('v.ltngParentFieldAPIName');
        //var tlabelFieldAPIName= component.get('v.ltngLabelFieldAPIName');
        if(trecid){
            helper.callToServer(
                component,
                "c.findHierarchyData",
                function(response) {
                    var expandedRows = [];
                    var apexResponse = response;
                    var roles = {};
                    console.log('*******apexResponse:'+JSON.stringify(apexResponse));
                    var results = apexResponse;
                    roles[undefined] = { Name: "Root", _children: [] };
                    apexResponse.forEach(function(v) {
                        expandedRows.push(v.Id);
                        roles[v.Id] = { 
                            accountName: v.Name ,
                            name: v.Id, 
                            Type:v.Type,
                            Industry:v.Industry,
                            AccountURL:'/'+v.Id,
                            _children: [] };
                    });
                    apexResponse.forEach(function(v) {
                        roles[v.ParentId]._children.push(roles[v.Id]);   
                    });                
                    component.set("v.gridData", roles[undefined]._children);
                    console.log('*******treegrid data:'+JSON.stringify(roles[undefined]._children));

                    component.set('v.gridExpandedRows', expandedRows);
                }, 
                {
                    recId: component.get('v.ltngcurrentRecId')
                }
            );    
        }




    }
})
```

**HELPER:**

```
({
    callToServer : function(component, method, callback, params) {
        console.log('Calling helper callToServer function');
        var action = component.get(method);
        if(params){
            action.setParams(params);
        }
        console.log(JSON.stringify(params));
        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            var state = response.getState();
            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                //alert('Processed successfully at server');
                callback.call(this,response.getReturnValue());
            }else if(state === "ERROR"){
                alert('Problem with connection. Please try again.');
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
})
```

**APEX CONTROLLER:**

```
public class AccountTreeHierarchySample {
@AuraEnabled
    public static List<Account> findHierarchyData(string recId){
        List<Account> accList = new List<Account>();
        string queryString = 'select id,name,type,industry,parentId from Account ';
        //Section to get all child account details from ultimate parent starts-------------------------
        List<String> currentParent      = new List<String>{};
        Integer level               = 0;
        Boolean endOfStructure      = false;
        //method to find ultimate parent of account
        string topMostparent = GetUltimateParentId(recId );
        system.debug('*******topMostparent:'+topMostparent);
        currentParent.add(topMostparent);
        system.debug('**********topMostparent:'+ currentParent);
        //Loop though all children
        string finalQueryString = '';
        List<Account>  queryOutput = new List<Account> ();
        while ( !endOfStructure ){  
            if( level == 0 ){
                finalQueryString = queryString + ' where id IN : CurrentParent ORDER BY ParentId  Limit 1000';
            } 
            else {
                finalQueryString = queryString + ' where ParentID IN : CurrentParent ORDER BY ParentId Limit 1000';
            }
            system.debug('********finalQueryString:'+finalQueryString);
            if(finalQueryString != null && finalQueryString !=''){
                try{
                    if(Limits.getLimitQueries()-Limits.getQueries()>0){
                        queryOutput = database.query(finalQueryString);
                        system.debug('***hierarchy level:'+level);
                    }else{
                        system.debug('****endOfStructure is true as SOQL limit reaches:');
                        endOfStructure = true;
                    }
                }catch(exception ex){ 
                    endOfStructure = true;
                }
            }
            system.debug('**queryOutput size:'+queryOutput);
            if( queryOutput.size() == 0 ){
                endOfStructure = true;
            }
            else{
                currentParent.clear();
                //iterating through query output
                for ( Integer i = 0 ; i < queryOutput.size(); i++ ){
                    currentParent.add(queryOutput[i].Id);
                    accList.add(queryOutput[i]);
                 }
            }
            level++;
        }
        system.debug('**********accList:'+accList);
        return accList;
    }

    // Find the tom most element in Heirarchy  
    // @return objId
    public static String GetUltimateParentId( string recId ){
        Boolean top = false;
        while ( !top ) {
            string queryString = 'select id ,name, ParentId from Account where Id =:recId LIMIT 1';
            Account acc = database.query(queryString);
            if ( acc.parentId != null ) {
                recId = acc.parentId;
            }else {
                top = true;
            }
        }
        return recId ;
    }

}
```

Comment: Have to add icon/image infront of AccountName which is from Static resource.

Comment: Do you have SVG icon in the static resource?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can not as there is no provision to add a custom icon, you can add the standard lightning Icons. Check the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:treeGrid/documentation).

Comment: Any other workaround is possible or we have to build our own component?

Comment: can we use formula field to display image in treegrid?

Comment: Not sure, there is no harm to try. Also, you can try to manipulate the dom in `onRender` event of the component.